# How to use stored procedure as input dataset in ADF (How to assign database it uses)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to run a stored procedure against a linkedservice (azure sql database) and output the result of that stored procedure to a dataset (azure sql database).

Is this possible?

I currently have ended up with this:

**Pipeline: It should use a stored procedure that is found on a database defined as a linkedservice and copy that over to the output dataset (an azure sql database)**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Pipeline.json",
  "name": "CopyGetViewsByDateRange",
  "properties": {
    "description": "<Enter the Pipeline description here>",
    "activities": [
      {
        "name": "CopyActivityTemplate",
        "type": "Copy",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "InputDataset"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "OutputDataset"
          }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
          "source": {
            "type": "SqlSource",
            "sqlReaderStoredProcedureName": "Analytics_GetViewsByDateRange2",
            "storedProcedureParameters": {
              "clientid": { "value": "12345", "type": "Int" },
              "startdateid": { "value": "20170421", "type": "Int" },
              "enddateid": { "value": "20170514", "type": "Int" }
            }
          },
          "sink": {
            "type": "SqlSink"
          }
        },
        "policy": {
          "concurrency": 1,
          "executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",
          "retry": 3,
          "timeout": "01:00:00"
        },
        "scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Minute",
          "interval": "15"
        }
      }
    ],
    "start": "2017-05-15T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-05-17T00:00:00Z"
  }
}
```

**Input dataset (Note the comments):**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Table.json",
  "name": "InputDataset",
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureSqlTable", // This surely needs to be a stored procedure type
    "linkedServiceName": "AnalyticsAMECDevDB",
    "structure": [
      {
        "name": "Client_Id",
        "type": "Int64"
      },
      {
        "name": "DimDate_Id",
        "type": "Int64"
      },
      {
        "name": "TotalContentViews",
        "type": "Int64"
      } // The structure represents what the stored procedure is outputting
    ],
    "typeProperties": {
      "tableName": "Analytics.FactPageViews" // This is obviously not right
    },
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Minute",
      "interval": "15"
    },
    "external": true
  }
}
```

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
SELECT 
        @clientid as Client_Id,
        [DimDateId] as DimDate_Id,
        count(1) as TotalContentViews
    FROM 
        [Analytics].[FactPageViews] as pageviews  
    inner join Analytics.DimPages as pages
        on pageviews.dimpageid = pages.id
    where 
        DimDateId between @startdateid and @enddateid
    group by 
        dimdateid
    order by 
        dimdateid
```

**EDIT (got something to work atleast)**

I am currently managing it by defining a query and running the command there:

```
"activities": [
  {
    "type": "Copy",
    "typeProperties": {
      "source": {
        "type": "SqlSource",
        "sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('EXEC [dbo].[GetViewsByDateRange] 2, 20170421, 20170514', WindowStart, WindowEnd)"
      },
      "sink": {
        "type": "SqlSink",
        "writeBatchSize": 0,
        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
      },
      "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "columnMappings": "Client_Id:Client_Id,DimDate_Id:DimDate_Id,TotalContentViews:TotalContentViews"
      }
    },
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "InputDataset-0af"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "OutputDataset-0af"
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got everything right. To answer your question. Simply, you don't need to have an input dataset defined in your pipeline/activity. So yes, certainly possible.

Just have the output dataset defined as the result of the stored proc.

Hope this helps

Comment: How will it know which database it is running the stored procedure against if no input is defined? Thanks for your help btw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this may help you to solve your problem,
Change your input and output dataset as below.

Input dataset

```
{
"$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Table.json",

    "name": "ofcspdataset",

    "properties": {

    "type": "AzureSqlTable",

    "linkedServiceName": "sproctestout",

    "typeProperties": {

      "tableName": "dbo.emp" ==> >>need to refer any table be in the source database.

    },

    "external": true,

    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Day",
      "interval": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Output  Dataset:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Table.json",

  "name": "OfficeTestOuputTable",

  "properties": {

    "published": false,

    "type": "AzureSqlTable",

    "linkedServiceName": "sproctestout",

    "structure": [

      { "name": "Id" },

      { "name": "GroupId" }
    ],

    "typeProperties": {

      "tableName": "dbo.testAdf_temp"

    },

    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Day",
      "interval": 1
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm sure your pipeline is good. Just try to change the input and output dataset.

For me its works.

Comment: My stored procedure joins many tables. Why would i need to add "tableName" if there are many tables that are required for the procedure?